# Center UIView inside UIScrollView using AutoLayout in the interface builder only

Tags: xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout, interface-builder

I'm trying to center a view inside a UIScrollView using the interface builder only. With labels seems to be working well.

[image] [image]

But when I try to do the same with a UIView, I'm having constraints conflicts.

[image] [image] [image]

The conflicts make sense, but if I delete the width/height constraints the UIView extends to the entire SuperView, and if I delete the top/lead/trail/bottom constraints, the UIView correctly centers itself, but I get an ambiguous width/height warning.

[image]

My question would be, How can I get the UIView centered the same as the UILabel?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference:

[image]
[image]

But the key thing was to set a different ContentHugging priority, to help AutoLayout work out conflicts:

[image]